# Property 'itemInstances' and 'processOrder' not valid in version 48.0 error when deploying in Production, even though Production is 49.0

Tags: deployment, production, api-version, mdapideploy

When trying to deploy the converted metadata using VS code `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy` deploy to my Production Org and I get the error `Property 'itemInstances' not valid in version 48.0` and `Property 'processOrder' not valid in version 48.0`. But when I go to `Developer Console` and open a class, even though it says 48.0, I have the option to select 49.0, so I am assuming I have 49.0. Yet I get this error. Pretty much all my classes, trigger and components are version 48.0, but I am not sure how that affects flexipages and Approval processes.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue.
Changing the version number in the `metadata.xml` didn't help, unfortunately.
However, when I increased the `sourceApiVersion` number in the `sfdx-projects.json` file (to 50.0 in my case), I was able to deploy the page.
Version number 49.0 will do the trick, too, since the `itemInstance` was introduced with version 49.0 (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm)).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is, in the converted metadata package which was created using `sfdx force:source:convert` there is a file called `package.xml`, search and replace 48.0 with 49.0 and it deploys.